# PSN Website My Lists Feature Doesn't Work

Tags: psn

I've searched for a similar problem and haven't had any luck. So here goes...

Signed in to [PlayStation US](http://us.playstation.com/), there is a feature called "My Lists". No matter which combination of filters I use I can't get any games to show up. A screenshot of this is below:

*Edited as of 2012-02-20 this is still not working properly in multiple browsers...*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While surfing the (super slow) PlayStation website, you can come across game pages, for example, [this one](http://us.playstation.com/games-and-media/games/uncharted-3-drakes-deception-ps3.html) for Uncharted 3. If you look at the right hand side of the page, you'll see this box:
[image: Link box]

If you click any of the marked links here, you'll add them to your wish list and/or games list:
[image: Link box with freehand circles]

You can find game pages using the search function on the column on the left

Comment: Horribly un-intuitive on Sony's part. Thanks for this!

Comment: Your name applies to their site design. UX doesn't seem to be PlayStation's strong point...